# XPATH to Excel Fails due to value unpacking

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to write a python script that will text from a web site and put it in excel. I'm able to request the data, but converting it to excel has given me some difficulty.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')

#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print( 'Buyers: ', buyers)
print( 'Prices: ', prices)

expenses = (buyers, prices)

#creating excel sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sales' + str(now) + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0


#write data to excel
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1


workbook.close()
```

Returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wRequests.py", line 32, in 
    for item, cost in (expenses):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How do unpack these values and load them into excel properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will do your job:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')

#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print( 'Buyers: ', buyers)
print( 'Prices: ', prices)

#creating excel sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sales' + str(now) + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

#write data to excel
for index, buyer in enumerate(buyers):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     buyer)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, prices[index])
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

**Explanation**

Right now your `expenses` variable is a touple with two list. It's structure is

```
(
    ['Carson Busses', 'Earl E. Byrd', 'Patty Cakes'],
    ['$29.95', '$8.37', '$15.26']
)
```

And `for` loop doesn't works like the way you'r using it on that data. It's basic syntax is:

```
for item in collection:
    print(item)
```

but you are using it like:

```
for item, cost in (expenses):
    print(item, cost)
```

You will not get `item` and `cost` separately when you are running the loop this way. You will get only **one single element** from your `expenses` touple at a time not multiple. Basically your syntax is wrong.

So now if you run it like

```
for single_item in (expenses):
    print(single_item)
```

The the output will be:

```
['Carson Busses', 'Earl E. Byrd', 'Patty Cakes'] # output for first iteration
['$29.95', '$8.37', '$15.26'] # output for second iteration
```

You see we are not getting `item` and `cost` together. At first we are getting first list which is your `item` and at second iteration we are getting the second list which is `cost`.

After examining `buyers` and `prices` variable I find that they excellently has same number of items and **one `list`'s corresponding item to other `list` sit at the same `index` as his own**. So I can pick a list arbitrary, iterate over it with index and use that index to find it's corresponding item in other list. It is as simple as that. Like:

```
for index, buyer in enumerate(buyers):
    print(buyer, prices[index])
```

Then it will give output as

```
Carson Busses $29.95
Earl E. Byrd $8.37
Patty Cakes $15.26
```

I can also write the `for` loop as

```
for index, buyer in enumerate(buyers):
    print(buyers[index], prices[index])
```

Which will give the same output. Note the python's builtin `enumerate` function return both `index` and `value` for each item of a list.

And if you had any other piece of data like `customers` you can just refer the `index` to find the customer. Like following:

```
for index, buyer in enumerate(buyers):
    print(buyer, prices[index], customers[index])
    # or you can also do this
    print(buyers[index], prices[index], customers[index])
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Forgive my naivety, I see what's different here, but I'm not clear on how you turned that data into columns on excel.  What if you had a third piece of data:  customers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="customer-name"]/text()').   I'm just trying to understand how you did this a little better.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost) 
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, customer)
    row += 1.                                                                                      Is this correct for a third row?

Comment: I have updated the answer with more explanation. Please check